# iOS 7.1 update from a PC causes my phone dead

Tags: iphone

I try to update my iphone 5S to iOS7.1 from a PC. The software update was downloaded and in the process of installing the update the internet connection was was disconnected for unknown reason. My phone's screen show an iTune symbol. I cannot use my phone any more. I want to know what happenep to my iphone. Can I use my phone again?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you did a backup before updating? Right? ;-)

If you have a backup file you simply plugin the iPhone to your computer and follow the last step in [this guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1766) ("Restore from a backup").

If you didn't make a backup, try to put your iPhone in DFU mode ([guide here](http://www.wikihow.com/Put-an-iPod-or-iPhone-into-DFU-Mode)) and follow the iTunes instructions to restore the iPhone to default. (You will lose your stuff if you haven't backed it up earlier)